# SIGABRT when adding objects to array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

```
enemyBlobArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0; i < kEnemyCount; i++) {
    [enemyArray addObject:[SpriteHelpers setupAnimatedSprite:self.view numFrames:3 withFilePrefix:@"greenbox" withDuration:((CGFloat)(arc4random()%2)/3 + 0.5) ofType:@"png" withValue:0]];
}

enemyView = [enemyArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

I am trying to make objects appear on screen from this array.
I get an error message saying that the object I add cannot be `nil`. I don't know why it's `nil`, though.

Comment: `[SpriteHelpers setupAnimatedSprite:numFrames:withFilePrefix:withDuration:ofType:withValue:]` (what a mouthful!) is returning `nil`. We can't possibly help you without knowing what that method does!

Answer (score 2):

The method `setupAnimatedSprite:numFrames:withFilePrefix:withDuration:ofType:withValue:` is returning nil. So the problem is somewhere inside that method. Since we don't have the code for that method, I couldn't tell you what it might be.

Answer (score 1):

According to the provided code, you make no mention of the allocation and initialization of "enemyArray"; however, you created a mutable array called "enemyBlobArray" which is never utilized within the provided code. Perhaps this is a simple issue of misspelling of a variable name.